# Volley body 400 error

Tags: http, post, text, android-volley

I want to send a POST to a server with the body that is true or false. I have this code and I use the Volley library

ShoozyHeader() set Content type to text/plain and Accept to text/plain and other headers necessary for the authentication.

If I try on http://requestmaker.com/ and the server responds correctly but I run this code the server responds:

Bad Request - Invalid Header
HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

If I remove the getBody() the server respond fine.

```
    final String url = POSTS_URI + idPost + "/likes";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(act, "Network error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return "true".getBytes();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it worked fine for me:

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

try {
    params.put("likes", "true");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, params,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

};
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

// Adding request to request queue
getRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you override getHeaders in your class that extends the Request ?

Here is how to:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}
```

Here is an example for seting up a Base64 (username, password) header:

```
@Override
    private HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", getAuthentication("usernameExample", "passwordExample"));
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        Log.d(TAG + "");
        return headers;
    }

private String getAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", username, password);
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return auth;
    }
```